# c# and variable fonts

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

to use [Asap font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Asap) with static fonts:

```
var collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
collection.AddFontFile(@"D:\Asap\static\Asap-Medium.ttf");
collection.AddFontFile(@"D:\Asap\static\Asap-MediumItalic.ttf");
var font = new Font(collection.Families.First(), 14, FontStyle.Regular);
```

how to get the same font using the variable font files (`Asap-VariableFont_wght.ttf` and `Asap-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf`) and passing the weight axis?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Are you using WPF? GDI+?

Comment: @PeterConstable WinForms

Comment: In what environment are you running this?  When I do this on my PC, each call to `AddFontFile` adds multiple `FontFamily` objects to `collection`.  When I run on my Raspberry Pi using Mono, only the first is added and I cannot tell how to use any of the latter variations.  Please, post an answer to your question if you've found one as you may help me (or someone else) out.